# spring multi-module project starting

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, maven

i am using spring framework to produce a web application .
i prefered to use multi module project to make my app readable .
this is the hierarchy of my project [image]

my parent project pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.ireview</groupId>
    <artifactId>IReviewParent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <ireview.version>${project.version}</ireview.version>
        <start-class>ireview.DemoApplication</start-class>


    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>IReview-exceptions</module>
        <module>IReview-domain</module>
        <module>IReview-data</module>
        <module>IReview-api</module>
        <module>IReview-security</module>
        <module>IReview-main</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
<!--                    <jmxPort>9001</jmxPort>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

when i launch my app from intellij it starts well , but the problem occurs when i try to launch it from command line with (mvn spring-boot:start) the error below appears

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.6:start (default-cli) on project IReviewParent: Could not contact Spring Boot application: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.CommunicationException [Root exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: Error unmarshaling return header; nested exception is: 
[ERROR]     java.net.SocketException: Connection reset]
```

also i want to know . if i want to host my app i need a jar to put it in the host , where do i get it from  ? how to launch it from cmd line ?
please help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

To launch it from command line run:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

The jar you can find inside /target directory

Comment: As you can see above there is no target directory in IReviewParent , also i've trie this cmd but the problem is the same